# Ошибка Python: SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python

```
a = int(input("Длина комнаты: 6"))
b = int(input("Ширина комнаты: 8"))

p = (a+b)*2
s = a*b

print("Периметр:",p)
print("Площадь:",s)
```

Comment: Метка [python-2.x] здесь явно не к месту. Это третий питон. Иначе было бы `raw_input`, а не `input`!

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 3):

Подобная ошибка возникает, когда вы вводите код из нескольких строк в интерпретаторе, вместо того, чтобы запускать свой код из редактора. Вставьте код в редактор и ошибка исчезнет (ваш код сам по себе синтаксически верный).

Наглядное пособие в одной картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно в конце каждой строки `;` поставить, тогда может и в интерпретаторе будет работать )